# ASP.NET Core 5.0.9 with EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.9 strange behavior on scaffolding new Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have updated EntityFrameworkCore and its dependencies to version 5.0.9 (.Design, .Tools. SqlServer), as well as installed all .Net 5.0.9 packages.
On Scaffolding new Razor Page, dependency EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and EntityFrameworkCore.Tools get downgraded to version 5.0.8.
Regarding the downgrade, I always get the error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=5.0.9.0".

Running the application and navigating to the page using data from Sql always returns error EntityFrameworkCore.dll -> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Any advice?
Regards

Comment: 5.0.9 versions work for me in a console app.

Comment: It is extremely strange how VS (16.11.2) can downgrade two dependencies on Scaffolding new Page